# DataFrame with a column whichs value should increase by 1 for every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame

```
    t                 Messzeit  BASET_2       CO2  CO2_pressure  base_rate  \
89,23  2021-08-23 08:59:52.938594   0.5050  0.524611         1.058        NaN   
89,27  2021-08-23 08:59:57.951421   0.5075  0.537082         1.058   1.795392   
89,33  2021-08-23 09:00:02.966091   0.5100  0.550867         1.058   1.794733   
90,12  2021-08-23 09:00:07.968342   0.5125  0.560317         1.058   1.799188   
91,44  2021-08-23 09:00:12.975224   0.5150  0.565553         1.058   1.79752
```

I want to add a new column where the value starts at 0 (because the dataFrame has 0 rows to that point in time) and ends with an integer that is the same number as there are rows.
So, for example, the value in the new column should be 4 in row 4, 5 in row 5, 6 in row 6,...

The index in this dataFrame occupied with other values, so that wouldn´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `range`:

```
df['counter'] = range(len(df))
```

output:

```
       t                    Messzeit  BASET_2       CO2  CO2_pressure  base_rate  counter
0  89,23  2021-08-23 08:59:52.938594   0.5050  0.524611         1.058        NaN        0
1  89,27  2021-08-23 08:59:57.951421   0.5075  0.537082         1.058   1.795392        1
2  89,33  2021-08-23 09:00:02.966091   0.5100  0.550867         1.058   1.794733        2
3  90,12  2021-08-23 09:00:07.968342   0.5125  0.560317         1.058   1.799188        3
4  91,44  2021-08-23 09:00:12.975224   0.5150  0.565553         1.058   1.797520        4
```

Comment: @jezrael I just saw it after you closed. Btw, do you think `np.arange` would have any advantage over `range`?

Comment: I think not, maybe if really large dtaframe should be some difference.

Comment: I guess if you need to make calculations, like `np.arange(…)+1`

Comment: if need calculation in created process, then yes, else not.

Comment: Do you think answer should be converted to wiki, because dupe?

Comment: No clue, I never did it, do as you think is the best.

Comment: Use `edit` and then tick in right `Community wiki`